stab towards goal
Can you explain what "stab" means in this context?

West Ham 2-1 Wolves (80 mins)
Lukasz Fabianski gets his gloves dirty again as Mario Lemina stabs towards goal. But again a clean view and an easy dive on the ball for the goalkeeper.


It is a metaphoric usage of the verb stab. Do you understand what a metaphor is?

@TimR I don't really understand. It basically means to injure someone with a sharp pointed object such as a knife. How can it mean to kick the ball? There is not the definition in dictionaries.

Did you look up metaphor in the dictionary?

@TimR Yes, I did. I think the word has a special meaning especially sports-related, but it's not listed in a dictionary.

It does not have special meaning. A very quick short-distance straight-line shot on goal. You cannot stab someone who is distant, and neither would the stab be successful if you took time to draw your arm back very far, telegraphing your intentions.  You're just not perceiving the analogy.

Footballers jab as well. Another knifey thing. _Cheikhou Kouyate has a jab towards goal but it is blocked and goes behind for a corner, which also comes to nothing for West Ham. _ (BBC Sport).

@MichaelHarvey The word "jab" has a meaning of "kick a ball hard and quickly" in the Cambridge Dictionary. It's also used in a match report and I often see it.

When you study English or whatever language, I recommend you should know the literal meaning of the words first and foremost. AND THEN, put the basic meaning into the interpretation. If the meaning is not clear, it was figuratively or metaphorically used.(But you can still get the hang of the meaning in most cases though there are some cases where you can't get the meaning: idioms or phrasal verbs.)
As for "kick the bucket", for example, you must know the meaning of 'kick' and the word 'bucket'. This phrase can have two meanings:


He kicked the bucket in front of him because he was angry.




He kicked the bucket and it's sad that he's not alive anymore.


1 means that he physically kicked the bucket (hit the bucket) with his foot.
2 means figuratively that he died.
The figurative usage has its own history and usually there is some reason why it got to have that usage.
Just could imagine any situation on your own to effectively remember the real usage meaning.
For instance, he slipped on the slippery floor in the bathroom and fell to the floor while kicking the bucket and died on the spot.
Remember: you must understand the literal meaning of the words first and foremost before you get to know the figurative usage because it's the fastest way to exactly understand and use a dazzling variety of language registers.


The phrase to stab home describes a type of goal. In this phrase, home refers to the goal and to stab describes a quick shot very close to the goal line, usually with the front part of the foot. The player connects with the ball with the toe of his or her boot and ‘stabs home’ – scores from close range [emphasis added].

Languagecaster
Edit
Here the word stab is used metaphorically, with the foot the symbolic sharp or pointed object commonly
used in stabbing.

Can you tell me the word "stab" to mean to kick in a dictionary?

As Tim says, it doesn't literally mean 'to kick'. Oxford Languages gives as a secondary definition make a thrusting gesture or movement at something with a pointed object. (here, the player's foot.)

@dwi ardianto, Kate and TimR have explained well.  Not all uses of a word are in the dictionaries.   A lot of them are metaphors.

I'm sure it has a broader use in sports context. Certainly, we have to use our imagination to understand this stuff.

@dwiardianto - People are having a stab at explaining the meaning, and no knives or indeed any pointy things are involved.

@MichaelHarvey The noun "stab" has a meaning of "attempt" so it's clear from the context.

@dwiardianto  Lexicography can be rather subjectve.  Dictionary entries are the result of an editorial decision by some person or committee, and lexicographers often go overboard in offering definitions for each context in which a word is used, when they could define the word  in terms of its salient characteristics and say that it is used figuratively in a variety of contexts ranging from military maneuvers to sport.
